# Unable to change Docky configuration in Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: lubuntu, docky

This maybe a stupid question, with easy fix. But I searching around to no avail.

I'm unable to change docky configuration, I tried opening the docky setting on the dock, but the option to make it hide was grayed out.

[image: Docky settings]

How would I modify the option ? Or is the Docky project really dead, before Docky I'm using Plank but it doesn't have animation. If Plank has animation, I would stay with that.

FYI: I install it with `sudo apt install docky`

Comment: Please mention the version of Lubuntu. And the last release seems to be from 2015-09-02 according to the [Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/docky/2.2).

Comment: I use Lubuntu 18.04

Comment: One of Docky's developers is keeping Plank development going: https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/ubuntu/docky?field.series_filter=bionic

Comment: I used Plank before and it's good, but their dock is static, I want it to have animation.

Comment: There's a small animation at the time of loading an appllcation: https://youtu.be/FPSIh2VRrvY?t=290. I guess you want an animation when you hover over an icon in the panel. I don't use Docky or Plank and so I hope someone else comes along to help!

Comment: Correct, I want it to behave like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To make Plank show animation on hover with Compton as the compositor

Open a terminal and run `plank --preferences`

You'll get a window looking like this:

[image: Plank preferences to set animation on hover]

You can adjust the value of *Icon zoom* to suit your needs.

### Compositing

- Lubuntu 18.04 comes with its own compositor called Compton which you can start from *Menu > Accessories > compton*.
- There's also a very nice interface for adjusting Compton's settings. This GUI is called *Window Effects* and is found under *Menu > Preferences > Window Effects*.
- Once you start Compton make the changes you want in Window Effects, go to *Menu > Preferences > Default applications for LXSession* and in the window that opens, add Compton to your *Autostart* as in the image below.

[image: Setting Compton to Autostart]

Comment: Is compton Lubuntu default apps ? I never noticed it !

Comment: I already done what you did, but Plank doesn't enlarge when hover.

Comment: xD my bad, I changed the configuration and it worked perfectly now. Thanks Dk

Comment: Plus, compton needs to run. I was about to upload a small video to YouTube so that you could see it working!

Comment: Yeah, I figured compton is not default apps, but require `compton` to be installed. However when I run `compton` from terminal, it makes the desktop buggy. When I launch them from menu, it doesn't, weird huh?

Comment: Plank now behaves the want I want, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

After searching around, it turns out Docky require compositing in order to work properly, and compositing reside in Compiz window manager.

So I tried to find the workaround, and found the fix:

```
sudo apt install xcompmgr
```

or

```
sudo apt install compton ###I USE THIS
```

Both will apply compositing, which enable Docky full capabilities.

[image: Docky settings after compositing]

However, there are price to pay. The compositing made Lubuntu desktop buggy, for example:

- Desktop background only shows gray color.
- Screen tearing
- etc.

I guess Im gonna stick with Plank, the dock that works stable on Lubuntu without further hack.

Answer (score -1):

user of Lubuntu 20.04,i got the same problem as you guys.

Well first I install Plank using Discover Apps,then Idk how to make the Plank show up after the login. From the reference above,I followed it,but nothing happens. Then I do this

[I did like what he did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ODrw.jpg)

[I go to this,then you can see my compton is already start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlNVq.jpg)

[After doing that,i go to this part,and start to make a new apps that is automatically appear after login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dn02K.jpg)

[And fill the name with Plank,and the "Perintah" which is mean Execution with that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZzoS.jpg)

If you wondering where i get that syntax in "Perintah" part,you can see this
[You can click Find button beside the Execution or "Perintah" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgiDg.jpg)

And then restart it.

Github : Nura21
Ohh you can see the image if you click my writing

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.